# import NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION question?

Tags: r, import, package

When installing a package R will look at the 'Depends' and 'Imports' in
the DESCRIPTION file to see which additional packages need installing.

When attaching 'library()' the package to an R session then R will load
any packages listed under 'Imports' and attach any listed under 'Depends'.

My question is regarding importing functions in the NAMESPACE
file? I'm confused as to the purpose of importing functions in that file
and exactly what it's doing.

Are imported functions in the NAMESPACE file attached to the R session
when the main package is attached?

If the answer is yes then is this not what 'Depends' is already doing? The
only difference i can see is that individual functions can be attached to
the session using NAMESPACE where as 'Depends' attaches the entire package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest reading [the Namespaces chapter](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) of Hadley's R Packages book. But in short, the answer is No.

> Are imported functions in the NAMESPACE file attached to the R session when the main package is attached?

No, they are not. Imported functions are available for use in the package internals, but not attached to the user's search tree.

Another source for info is, of course, [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html). They describe IMPORTS as:

> The ‘Imports’ field lists packages whose namespaces are imported from (as specified in the NAMESPACE file) but which do not need to be attached.

---

As a demonstration, the current version of `ggplot2`, v 3.2.1, has `import(scales)` in its NAMESPACE file. In a fresh R session, we can load `ggplot2` and observe that the `scales` package is not attached:

```
library(ggplot2)
percent(1)
# Error in percent(1) : could not find function "percent"
scales::percent(1)
# [1] "100%"
```

`ggplot2` uses functions from `scales` internally, and can do so without using the `package::function` notation. This is what the `import(scales)` accomplishes. However, unlike with `Depends`, `scales` is not attached for the user.

Comment: [This](https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/depends.html) is another intresting source. What I would add to this answer is that packages in `Depends` "are to be loaded (with `library()`) whenever your package is loaded". One example where this makes sense is the [`rvest`](https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) package which automatically loads `xml2`

Comment: Right, OP doesn't seem at all confused about Depends. The second paragraph of the question mentions is completely accurate. *"When attaching 'library()' the package to an R session then R will... attach any listed under 'Depends'"*. And again at the end of the question, *"'Depends' attaches the entire package."* Since it's accurately stated in the question without any confusion indicated, I don't see a need to restate it in the answer.

Comment: Fair enough maybe I projected my own surprise from when I learned about this detail.